# What does this mean inputFlag = False and then while not inputFlag?

Tags: python

I am having trouble understanding what this means. I need somebody to explain why without `inputFlag = False`, the code won't work and why do we need `while not`?

```
inputFlag = False 
while not inputFlag:
    try:
        hiNum = int(input("Please Enter a number at least 10: "))
        while hiNum < 10 :
            print ("The number must be at least 10.")
            print ("Try again.")
            hiNum = int(input("Please Enter a number at least 10: "))
        else:
           inputOk = True
           return
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter numbers 10 or 10 and up.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Analyse the difference between these two:

```
while inputFlag:
```

and

```
while not inputFlag:
```

These evaluate to:

```
while inputFlag == True:
```

and

```
while inputFlag == False:
```

This is just considered pythonic. You can use either corresponding way; both will work.

Comment: technically it should be `while bool(inputFlag) != True` but yeah solid answer

Comment: @JoranBeasley Not necessarily. There's no point to add the `bool`. It won't do anything since `inputFlag` is already a bool.

Comment: `inputFlag = None` would still be falsey but `None != False` so it would not  quite be the same behaviour (or an empty string or any number of falsey values) ... really its a technicality ... not a big deal and it will work perfectly fine for OP

Comment: and `bool(None)` doesn't do anything. It returns False, so then what's your point?

Comment: of coarse since `inputFlag` is never actually changed they may as well have used `while True:`

Comment: It's a `bool` for a reason. Do this if there is no input. Simple as that

Comment: `while not inputFlag: ` is not quite the same as `while inputFlag == False:` thats all ... there are many many falsey values other than false who knows how inputFlag becomes non-falsey in the original code (or if it ever does ...)